# Achievements during warmup

Tags: achievements, counter-strike-global-offensive

In CS:GO, can I work towards achievements like "X kills with weapon Y" during warmup in competitive mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checked my kill count on a weapon I don't use (M249) before I played competitive last night, I managed to get 3 kills with it in warm-up and my achievement count had increased by 3 after the match.

So yes, kills in competitive warm-up do count towards your achievements.